# Can I change update settings for individual tiles? some tiles as static and some as live?

Tags: live-tiles

Can I change update settings for individual tiles? some tiles as static and some as live? I interested in buying a new phone and am inclining towards a windows, but I 've heard that live tiles may get annoying and static tiles seems not much different than icons to me. Integration of both may solve this problem. Can someone answer me, ASAP.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Some apps let you control how the live tile for it updates. But if they do not, you can try turning off background tasks for the app. Often times the app's background task will update the tile. But this does not guarantee it. Also certain tiles like flip and cycle, can move without being further updated.

Answer (score 0):

The only people that *I've seen criticise* the live tiles, don't own or use a Windows Phone.

The tile animations *automatically* stop after approx 30 seconds of inactivity, and not every tile has animation, even if they do update periodically (so things like email only animate for the second when a new email is received to change the number, etc.).

Like any buying decision, it is often best to get your hands on a real device and play with it to get a feeling on how it would work for you - in my experience, it's only got better over time, as I've customised the tiles of interest to me.